# Randomly present different tasks on each trial

Tags: psychopy

I use Psychopy v1.81.02, so far I tried the Builder.

My aim is to program an experiment in which 32 sounds are presented with each of two different tasks. The two tasks differ in the instruction (before the sound is played) and the rating (after the sound was played). The sounds as well as the tasks occur randomly on each trial, i.e. each sound is assigned to both tasks once and the tasks occur randomly. In the end, with 32 sounds, it runs 64 trials: each sound twice with both tasks, but both sounds and tasks are randomised across trials.

In the Builder, I created two routines: 
Routine 1 (= task 1) consists of instruction_1 + sound_1 + rating_1 and
Routine 2 (= task 2) consists of instruction_2 + sound_1 + rating_2.

To call the sounds, I included a .csv file with one parameter “audiofile” and 32 conditions (the sound files) and put it on “random”. That works as far as the randomization of the sounds goes, but how can I make the tasks occur in a random order? I tried to put a loop around the routines, but didn't know what to put "in there" to randomize two routines - is that even possible?

Answer (score 0):

As you suspected, you will need to nest additional loops within your current one. In essence, you will put a loop around each of your tasks and give it a repetitions value of 0 or 1 to determine whether it occurs on a given trial.

(1) Structure your .csv file so it looks like the example below: each sound filename occurs twice, because it will be presented on two trials. There are two other columns which specify which of the tasks will occur on that trial, which will be counterbalanced:

```
soundFile    routine_1_reps    routine_2_reps
snd01.wav    0                 1
snd01.wav    1                 0
snd02.wav    0                 1
snd02.wav    1                 0    
etc...
```

(2) Insert a loop **only** around Routine_1 and another **only** around Routine_2, called, say, Routine_1_loop and Routine_2_loop. i.e. these loops are nested within the main loop. Don't connect them to a .csv file. Put the variable names "routine_1_reps" and "routine_2_reps" in their reps fields. This way, only one of the tasks will be presented on each trial.

Set the main, outer loop to be random. Then you should get each sound played twice but in randomised order. Only one task will occur on each of those trials, again in random order.

Comment: Routine_1_loop.nreps = routineOrder[]
NameError: name 'Routine_1_loop' is not defined

Comment: The spelling of the names of the inner loops correspond to the piece of code.
The new Routines 0 and 3 are put in the flow as follows: Routine_0 inside the main_loop (with the sounds in the .csv file) and Routine_3 inside both, the task_loop (2) and the main_loop.
Here is a scetch how the flow looks like with the loops in parantheses:

(main_loop_sound) Routine_0 (task_loop) (Routine_1_loop) Routine_1 (Routine_1_loop) (Routine_2_loop) Routine_2 (Routine_2_loop) Routine_3 (task_loop) (main_loop_sound)

Comment: The original code I posted was referring to the loops before they had been instantiated, hence causing the "name not defined" error. I've amended the code to now use variables rather than directly trying to access the loop reps property. +1 for the way of representing the loop structure in text.

Comment: i.e. as well as changing the code above, make sure to put the variable names "routine_1_reps" and "routine_2_reps" in the reps field of the two inner-most loops.

Comment: It runs... but not the way I want it. Routine_3 says: Play the task that was not played in the previous run WITHOUT picking a new sound for it - the new sound is picked after both tasks were presented once (in a shuffled order, though). It runs like: sound1+task1, sound1+task2, sound2+task2, sound2+task1 etc. But I want that each sound was assigned randomly to one task once and that the tasks occur randomly. In the end, with 32 sounds, I will have 64 presentations: each sound twice with both tasks.

Comment: OK, must have misinterpreted the phrasing in your original question, which is a bit ambiguous (describing designs like is tricky without a diagram...). The answer to this is now much simpler: much of the logic can go in your .csv file. I'll re-write the answer accordingly, and change the title of the question, which isn't quite correct now.

Comment: Did the revised answer achieve what you needed? If so, please mark it as accepted for future readers. If not, let us know the details.